# How do I get all element contents of a html by using Cheerio?

Tags: cheerio

I want to scrape all element contents(every text between every tag) of a html webpage and want them to be stored in an array. I made some trials as below but it doesn't' seem to work. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url3 = 'https://www.amazon.com';

const array = [];
request({url: url3,  json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) 
    { return console.log(err); }
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('*').each(function(i, element){
    array.push($(this).text());
  });

  console.log(array)
});
```

Comment: It was not about cheerio but request. when it sends request to 'https://www.amazon.com" the body in the response is not an html string. It is somewhat like cryptofied string.

Comment: not so actually. Amazon returns regular html believe it or not.

Comment: Thank you pguardiario. Thing is the npm request module supported UTF encode by default not the others. Encode setting of "https://www.amazon.com' was ISO something.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What output did you expect, what did you get?